# Understanding meaning of filter in spring ldap

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap

> ```
> .userSearchBase("ou=people")
> .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
> .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
> .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
> ```

Could anyone explain me what does it mean these filter ?
Whats the difference between `base` and `search` filter ? Moreover, whoat does it mean `member={0}` ?

Answer (score 4):

As per [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configurers/ldap/LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.html)

```
public LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<B> userSearchBase(String userSearchBase)
```

> Search base for user searches. Defaults to "". Only used with userSearchFilter(String).
>   Parameters:
>   userSearchBase - search base for user searches
>   Returns:
>   the LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer for further customizations

`user-search-base` is used to point to the base path where to
   find user information.

```
public LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<B> userSearchFilter(String userSearchFilter)
```

> The LDAP filter used to search for users (optional). For example "(uid={0})". The substituted parameter is the user's login name.
>   Parameters:
>   userSearchFilter - the LDAP filter used to search for users
>   Returns:
>   the LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer for further customizations

`user-search-filter` is the attribute name that contains the user name.

```
public LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<B> groupSearchBase(String groupSearchBase)
```

> The search base for group membership searches. Defaults to "".
>   Parameters:
>   groupSearchBase -
>   Returns:
>   the LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer for further customizations

So `group-search-base` is the base path where to find role information.

```
public LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer<B> groupSearchFilter(String groupSearchFilter)
```

> The LDAP filter to search for groups. Defaults to "(uniqueMember={0})". The substituted parameter is the DN of the user.
>   Parameters:
>   groupSearchFilter - the LDAP filter to search for groups
>   Returns:
>   the LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer for further customizations

So `group-search-filter` is the attribute name that contains the full dn(distinguished name) of a user.